# Bit in the +/- form

Tags: bit-manipulation, operators, bit

I recently wondered about why not just use one bit as "+/-" and use the other as a number module? Will their use not be rational or are there some other factors that prevent this from being done?

Comment: @harold, yes, it is something similar

Comment: FWIW IEEE floating point does kind of do that, but for integers the TL;DR is that sign and magnitude representation is more complicated in hardware and also has two zeros (+0 and -0).